# docker-compose of Nginx image doesn't work when the docker-compose.yml file is moved

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

## INTRODUCTION :

Hello, I have project named **time_manager** that contains a folder named **theme_02**.
 In the **theme_02** project folder, I have a `docker-compose.yml`, a `Dockerfile`, and all the source code of my **Vue** project.

```
-time_manager
   -theme_02
      -Dockerfile
      -docker-compose.yml
      -etc..
```

The `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:latest as build-stage

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --prefer-offline --no-audit
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build


FROM nginx as production-stage

RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

When I build the docker image with `docker build -t vue_front .` and run the docker container with `docker run -it -p 8080:80 vue_front`. it works fine, I can see my **Node** project

My `docker-compose.yml` file is:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    vue_front:
        build:
            ./.
        ports: 
            - "8080:80"
```

If I use the command `docker-compose up -d`, it also works perfectly, my **Node** project is loading correctly.

## ERROR :

When I try to move the `docker-compose.yml` inside the **time_manager**, such as:

```
-time_manager
   -docker-compose.yml
   -theme_02
      -Dockerfile
      -etc..
```

I don't forget to update the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    vue_front:
        build:
            ./theme_02
        ports: 
            - "8080:80"
```

I rebuild the docker images, and runs it, there is no error. 
**But** when I go `http://localhost:8080`, the page doesn't load.
It seems that moving the `docker-compose.yml` file up, create an error, which is strange since I did that for other projects and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `docker-compose` file is incorrect.
The `build` property should either be a `string` or an `object`.
You are providing neither and it is probably defaulting to the current directory for a build context.

Change to as follows

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    vue_front:
        build: ./theme_02
        ports: 
            - "8080:80"
```

See documentation for reference https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build

Answer (score 2):

You may have to specify the `build.context` field in the docker-compose definition and reference the Dockerfile (using `build.dockerfile` field) with the relative path from `context` folder.

See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build

Your `docker-compose.yml` should look like this :

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
    vue_front:
        build:
            context: ./theme_02
            dockerfile: Dockerfile #optional
        ports: 
            - "8080:80"
```

Comment: Indeed, the mistake was much simpler than I thought. thank you

Comment: @Flo - I believe that your solution is not fully correct. The context property in the above solution would be incorrect. The context should be `./theme_02` and the docker file can be left either empty or named. I believe the `dockerfile` property is there if the `Dockerfile` is named anything other than the default 'Dockerfile'. I believe your solution would give the same result as the OP originally reported. I'd suggest an edit.